# RegEx for at least an uppercase, a lower case, a number and a special character

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am writing an android regular express for checking a password which contains, the regex I used was

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W_]).{8,16}$
```

but my Matcher class always returns a false

```
     Matcher matcher;

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(context.getString(R.string.password_validation_value));

matcher = pattern.matcher(password); // always returns false
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Just put a quantifier after the dot in each assertion. Example `(?=.*\d)`. Also, don't use `\W` as this matches spaces and control characters. Or, use this instead `(?=.*(?=[\x21-\x7e])[\W_])`

Comment: @Aaron i dont fully understand

Comment: @sln please i dont understand your answer too, can you please explain further, plus i am new to this regex

Comment: Since you've edited your question my comment is invalid (and I've deleted it), but when you had `^(?=.\d)(?=.[a-z])` it meant "at the start of the string, check if the next character is whatever and the following is a digit. Also check if the next character is whatever and the following a lowercase letter". Of course that second character couldn't be both at the same time. Now that you use `(?=.*thing)` it's not a problem anymore as this will match the `thing` you're looking for anywhere in the string rather than specifically as the second character

Comment: `matcher = pattern.matcher(password);` does not return `false`. Do you run `matcher.matches()` after it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes i used matcher.matches() after

Comment: Please add the whole relevant code in the question to repro the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is an explanation

`^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\p{P}).{6,16}$`

Explained

```
 ^                     # Beginning of string
 (?= .* \d )           # Assert, string contains a digit
 (?= .* [a-z] )        # Assert, string contains a lower case letter
 (?= .* [A-Z] )        # Assert, string contains a upper case letter
 (?= .* \p{P} )        # Assert, string contains a punctuation character
 .{6,16}               # Consume 6 to 16 characters
 $                     # End of string
```